# calculate returns with inflows/outflows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes: one with two columns representing a value date and the total balance on an account; the second dataframe has also two columns with a value date and the amount of money added or substracted from the account on that date. I would like to calculate the performance (ie the percentage return between two dates on the first dataframe before any movement of cash stored in the second dataframe).

For clarity here is an example.

Account Balance dataframe:

| Date | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 05/06/2023 | 100 |
| 06/06/2023 | 110 |
| 07/06/2023 | 90 |
| 08/06/2023 | 120 |

Inflow/Outflow dataframe (here I assume 20 was added to the account on the 7th of June):

| Date | Movement |
| --- | --- |
| 07/06/2023 | 20 |

I would like to produce the following dataframe:

| Date | Performance |
| --- | --- |
| 05/06/2023 | N/A |
| 06/06/2023 | 10% |
| 07/06/2023 | -18.2% |
| 08/06/2023 | 9.1% |

On the 7th of June the performance is calculated before cash movements ie (90-110)/110 while  the performance on the 8th of June takes into account the cash transfer ie (120 - (90+20))/(90+20)

Of course the inflow/outflow dataframe can have more than one row. Is there a pythonic way to produce such dataframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
import pandas as pd

balance_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["05/06/2023", "06/06/2023", "07/06/2023", "08/06/2023"],
        "Balance": [100, 110, 90, 120],
    }
)

flow_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["07/06/2023"],
        "Movement": [20],
    }
)

balance_flow_df = pd.merge(balance_df, flow_df, on="Date", how="outer")
balance_flow_df["BalanceWithMovement"] = balance_flow_df["Balance"] + balance_flow_df["Movement"].fillna(0)
balance_flow_df["Performance"] = (balance_flow_df["Balance"] / balance_flow_df["BalanceWithMovement"].shift(1)) - 1
print(balance_flow_df)
```

does pretty much what you want (keeping the extra columns in here so we can see where the math comes from):

```
         Date  Balance  Movement  BalanceWithMovement  Performance
0  05/06/2023      100       NaN                100.0          NaN
1  06/06/2023      110       NaN                110.0     0.100000
2  07/06/2023       90      20.0                110.0    -0.181818
3  08/06/2023      120       NaN                120.0     0.090909
```